# add text to the choice_label of ChoiceField in Django

Tags: django, widget

The ChoiceField creates a select html element and the options show the choice_label which is the __unicode__ of each model object.

How can I change the text of the choice_label without modifying __unicode__ ?

I have a Product model and I want to show in the options text the product name + price + link to edit.

I've searched in fields.py and widgets.py but couldn't find what needed to be changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The from field class, eg. `ModelChoiceField` has a method `label_from_instance` that you can override in your subclass. 
Originally it looks like this:

```
def label_from_instance(self, obj):
    return smart_unicode(obj)
```

Should be no big problem to adjust this to your needs!